# Can reading fine print cause damage to eyes?

Tags: biology, computers, ophthalmology

I have my computer font set quite small so that I can see more on one screen at a time, but a collegue recently warned me that I would cause damage to my eyes later in life. Is there any scientific evidence to support this claim?

Not sure how widely believed this is. I asked because for every article claiming it [doesn't](http://www.preventblindness.org/sites/default/files/national/documents/fact_sheets/FS20_CommonEyeMyths_0.pdf) damage your eyes, there are numerous [articles](http://www.abc.net.au/health/features/stories/2014/10/23/4113106.htm) [claiming](http://yoursightmatters.com/tiny-screens-can-cause-big-vision-problems/) [it does](https://www.firmoo.com/answer/question/6361.html)

Comment: Welcome to skeptics.SE! We only accept questions which contain a notable claim, thus "my colleague told me"-type questions are off-topic. If you can add a reference that this is believed by a significant amount of people, please feel free to add it, and I'll redact my close vote.

Comment: @tim Thanks for the welcome. Not sure what counts as a reference but there are plently of results for it on Google, I've added a few to my question. Let me know what you think.

Comment: abc.net.au would definitely be a good source to show notability, but I can't find the claim there. Q&A sites are generally not that great to show notability, but the third site seems fine to me, so I'll retract my close vote.

Comment: Since I don't have definitive proof, I'll just comment - I think it's more that your eyes lose their elasticity, so one gets greater eye strain (or more lasting effects from it) from the activities later in life, not so much that it actually is damaging the eyes.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet yes the claim certainly seems plausable and that would make sense, I just don't know enough about biology to know if it is a risk worth considering or if I can continue to use a small font.

Comment: @tim Ah yes, I suppose I was reading the section about computer screens. They do link to http://www.abc.net.au/health/talkinghealth/factbuster/stories/2010/09/30/3025732.htm which says under "Minimising the risk" to increase the font size.

Comment: @tim My native language is not English and I've seen several times it being said by adults when I was a child, couple decades ago. This question has my upvote, it is notable. Googling in my native language brings 608k results when the phrase is in quotes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The "damage" done by screens is in the form of eye strain.  Your eyeball focuses by using muscles in the eye to change the shape of the lens within the eye, to properly focus incoming light onto the correct portion of the retina.

> It is the second part of your eye, after the cornea, that helps to focus light and images on your retina. Because the lens is flexible and elastic, it can change its curved shape to focus on objects and people that are either nearby or at a distance.

[VisionAware: Anatomy of the Eye](http://www.visionaware.org/info/eye-health/anatomy-of-the-eye/25)

Since we are talking about muscles physically manipulating the lens, constantly focusing on items at the same location will cause the actual muscles to fatigue.  This manifests itself as:

> Eye strain also known as asthenopia is an eye condition that manifests itself through nonspecific symptoms such as fatigue, pain in or around the eyes, blurred vision, headache, and occasional double vision. Symptoms often occur after reading, computer work, or other close activities that involve tedious visual tasks.

[Wikipedia: Eye Strain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_strain)

Once the muscles have had a chance to rest, the body recovers. Since eye-strain is a short-term condition, you are not actually "damaging" the eye.

> Eye strain facts. ... Extended computer use or inadequate or excessive lighting may cause eye strain, **but there are no permanent consequences of this**. Symptoms can include headaches, blurring of the vision, feelings of dryness, and other discomfort, but **eye strain will not damage your eyes or change their anatomy**.

[Medicinenet.com: Eye Strain](http://www.medicinenet.com/eye_strain/article.htm)

> Eyestrain doesn't have serious or long-term consequences, but it can be aggravating and unpleasant.

(Wish I could down-vote Mayo Clinic for using "aggravating" on their web site like that).

[Mayo Clinic: Eyestrain complications](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/eyestrain/basics/complications/con-20032649)

As one ages, like with many other types of tissues in the body, the lens of the eye becomes less flexible/more rigid, making it more difficult to manipulate for focus.  This would speed the onset of and increase the frequency of eye strain, as the muscles have to work harder.  This is why people (like me, who avoided glasses for almost 50 years) need reading glasses more often as they age.